LINQ with a Dynamic Query Fails in a Loop but not if entered in code - getting Index was outside the bounds of the array
I wanted to learn Azure Functions, this has nothing to do with that, it could be WebAPI I am sure. If you know Wordle, I was trying to make a practical "search" type program as something to work with. I am using .Net 8.
The intention is to let the user enter the letters they found an exact match for and what position they are at.
So my incoming model looks like this in my testing. I figured for the exact matches, the position or index of the character in the array is where it should be located within the word. I am not dealing with the other 2 properties of the model yet until I can fix this one.
{
  "ExactMatches": [ "", "", "a", "g", "e" ],
  "MissedMatches": [
    [ "", "", "", "", "" ],
    [ "", "", "", "", "" ],
    [ "", "", "", "", "" ],
    [ "", "", "", "", "" ],
    [ "", "", "", "", "" ],
  ],
  "UnusedCharacters": [ "p", "r", "i" ]
}

If I disregard the model and do it manually, everything works:
GetAllWords();

var query = AllWords.AsQueryable();

query = query.Where(x => x.Word[2].ToString() == "a");
query = query.Where(x => x.Word[3].ToString() == "g");
query = query.Where(x => x.Word[4].ToString() == "e");

var matches = query.ToList(); <-- This works

If I do it programmatically like this, it fails with Index was outside the bounds of the array
GetAllWords();

var model = await req.ReadFromJsonAsync<SearchModel>();
var query = AllWords.AsQueryable();

for (var position = 0; position < model.ExactMatches.Count; position++)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.ExactMatches[position]))
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"  {position} = {model.ExactMatches[position]}");
    query = query.Where(x => x.Word[position].ToString() == model.ExactMatches[position]);
  }
}

var matches = query.ToList(); <-- Exception happens here

The logging to the console gets me this and is correct, so the out of bounds is not trying to get say the 7th character of a 5 character long word:
Exact Matches
  2 = a
  3 = g
  4 = e

Here is the incoming model:
public class SearchModel
{
  public List<string> ExactMatches { get; set; }
  public List<List<string>> MissedMatches { get; set; }
  public List<string> UnusedCharacters { get; set; }
}

The "Words" are all 5 letters long and the object is this:
public class WordItem
{
  public required string Word { get; set; }
  public DateTime? DateUsed { get; set; }
}

Lastly, I grab the words for a local json file:
private void GetAllWords()
{
  var infilename = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Words.json");
  using var sr = new StreamReader(infilename);
  var json = sr.ReadToEnd();
  AllWords = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WordItem>>(json);
}

If it will help, here is a snippet of the json file:
[
  { "Word": "aalii", "DateUsed": null },
  { "Word": "aargh", "DateUsed": null },
  { "Word": "aarti", "DateUsed": null },
  { "Word": "abear", "DateUsed": null },
  { "Word": "abele", "DateUsed": null },
  { "Word": "abers", "DateUsed": null },
  { "Word": "abets", "DateUsed": null },
  { "Word": "abhor", "DateUsed": null },
  { "Word": "abide", "DateUsed": "2024-03-19T00:00:00" },
  { "Word": "abies", "DateUsed": null }
]

Doing this manuallay was incredibly quick and allowed me to focus on learning Azure Functions. This stupid error is killing me. At least if it were SQL, I could get the query string and see exactly what was going wrong here.
I've been searching around and using co-pilot with no luck thus far, so that you in advance for someone who can shed some light on this objsticle for me.

I have a gut feeling this is due to the position variable being captured in a closure. Can you try copying the position variable inside the for loop, and using that variable in your query instead? I.e. for (var position = 0; ...; position++) { var currentPosition = position; query = query.Where(x => x.Word[currentPosition].ToString() == ... - this other SO post explains it a bit more clearly: Captured variable in a loop in C#

In your question, there's a bit of code with a comment that says <-- Exception happens here, is that the exact line the exception happens on? Or is it saying that the exception happens in that code block?

@JoshHeaps yes, that is where the exception happens, that exact line.
